# Why, in React, do children not re-render when parent component re-renders(children are not wrapped by React.memo)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, rerender

In this article [React Hooks - Understanding Component Re-renders](https://medium.com/@guptagaruda/react-hooks-understanding-component-re-renders-9708ddee9928), I learned that when we use `useContext` Hook in parent component, only the children components **which consume the context** would re-render. 

And the article gives two way of consumptions of context. Take a look at the snippet:

[Efficient consumption of useContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqXhP.png)\

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TickerComponent from "./tickerComponent";
import ThemedTickerComponent from "./themedTickerComponent";
import { ThemeContextProvider } from "./themeContextProvider";
import ThemeSelector from "./themeSelector";

import "./index.scss";
import logger from "./logger";

function App() {
  logger.info("App", `Rendered`);
  return (
    <ThemeContextProvider>
      <ThemeSelector />
      <ThemedTickerComponent id={1} />
      <TickerComponent id={2} />
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const defaultContext = {
  theme: "dark",
  setTheme: () => {}
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(defaultContext);

export const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
  const setTheme = theme => {
    setState({ ...state, theme: theme });
  };

  const initState = {
    ...defaultContext,
    setTheme: setTheme
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "./themeContextProvider";

function ThemeSelector() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const onThemeChanged = theme => {
    logger.info("ThemeSelector", `Theme selection changed (${theme})`);
    setTheme(theme);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "10px 5px 5px 5px" }}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="dark"
          checked={theme === "dark"}
          onChange={() => onThemeChanged("dark")}
        />
        Dark
      </label>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="light"
          checked={theme === "light"}
          onChange={() => onThemeChanged("light")}
        />
        Light
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

module.exports = ThemeSelector;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "./themeContextProvider";
import TickerComponent from "./tickerComponent";
import { useContext } from "react";

function ThemedTickerComponent(props) {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return <TickerComponent id={props.id} theme={theme} />;
}

module.exports = ThemedTickerComponent;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import stockPriceService from "./stockPriceService";
import "./tickerComponent.scss";

function TickerComponent(props) {
  const [ticker, setTicker] = useState("AAPL");
  const currentPrice = stockPriceService.fetchPricesForTicker(ticker);
  const componentRef = React.createRef();

  setTimeout(() => {
    componentRef.current.classList.add("render");
    setTimeout(() => {
      componentRef.current.classList.remove("render");
    }, 1000);
  }, 50);

  const onChange = event => {
    setTicker(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="theme-label">
        {props.theme ? "(supports theme)" : "(only dark mode)"}
      </div>
      <div className={`ticker ${props.theme || ""}`} ref={componentRef}>
        <select id="lang" onChange={onChange} value={ticker}>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="NFLX">NFLX</option>
          <option value="FB">FB</option>
          <option value="MSFT">MSFT</option>
          <option value="AAPL">AAPL</option>
        </select>
        <div>
          <div className="ticker-name">{ticker}</div>
          <div className="ticker-price">{currentPrice}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

module.exports = TickerComponent;
```

[Inefficient consumption of useContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr5EP.png)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";
import TickerComponent from "./tickerComponent";
import ThemedTickerComponent from "./themedTickerComponent";
import { ThemeContextProvider } from "./themeContextProvider";
import { ThemeContext } from "./themeContextProvider";

function App() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const onThemeChanged = theme => {
    setTheme(theme);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ padding: "10px 5px 5px 5px" }}>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="dark"
            checked={theme === "dark"}
            onChange={() => onThemeChanged("dark")}
          />
          Dark
        </label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="light"
            checked={theme === "light"}
            onChange={() => onThemeChanged("light")}
          />
          Light
        </label>
      </div>
      <ThemedTickerComponent id={1} />
      <TickerComponent id={2} theme="" />
    </>
  );
}
```

In the **Inefficient consumption of useContext** example, the **child** component `TickerComponent (2)` which didn't consume context re-rendered since the **parent** `<App />` consumed context and re-rendered. But in **Efficient consumption of useContext** example, the **child** TickerComponent (2) didn't re-render even it's **parent** `<ThemeContxtProvider>` re-rendered because of consumption of context.

I learned that children without React.memo  will re-render when parent re-render, so why in **Efficient consumption of useContext** example that not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are considering code like

```
function ComponentToRender() {
  const count = React.useRef(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('component rendered', count.current++)
  })

  return null
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>You clicked {count} times!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      <ComponentToRender />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and

```
function ComponentToRender() {
  const count = React.useRef(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('component rendered', count.current++)
  })

  return null
}

function Clicker({ children }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>You clicked {count} times!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Clicker>
      <ComponentToRender />
    </Clicker>
  );
}
```

equivalent. While they do the same thing, and behave more or less in the same way, the second example will render `ComponentToRender` only once, even after pressing the "increment" button multiple times. (while the first one will re-render each time the button is pressed.)

The concept apply to your example as well. Your "inefficient consumption" will trigger a re-render from `App`, and force a refresh to every direct child of that component. The "efficient consumption" doesn't, because that's not the case. In my simplified example, `ComponentToRender` is actually rendered by `App`, not `Clicker`. So a change in state of `Clicker` will not impact `ComponentToRender` (that was just passed as children)

Another way for `App` to be written, in the second example, is:

```
function App() {
  const componentToRenderWithinApp = <ComponentToRender />

  return (
    <Clicker>
      {componentToRenderWithinApp}
    </Clicker>
  );
}
```

this one is equivalent to `<Clicker><ComponentToRender /></Clicker>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But IMHO, `ComponentToRender` is pasted to `Clicker` as a children, so why a change in state of `Clicker` will not impact `ComponentToRender`? That's what I cannot understand.

Comment: ![draft](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tuchuang-ml/tuchuang@fb143d3ff87bb3bcccc2ce115f6c3c859a37d128/2021/10/03/f620ca9d9c9db11abe99ed4c44212998.png)

Comment: In your image, ComponentToRender is not actually a direct children of Clicker > div, It's actually a level above. You should position it under App in you tree representation.

Comment: ComponentToRender is pasted to Clicker as children prop, so why should position it under App?

Comment: The difference is that it's App that created ComponentToRender. The position don't matter (i.e, that I passed that element to be rendered inside clicker). A change in state in clicker will not require a re-render, because the only way for ComponentToRender to require one is for App to change

Comment: I wrote a code here: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-spence-us531?file=/src/App.js)
And this is the Dom of the snippet [dom_pic](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tuchuang-ml/tuchuang@19af338a6764b08a80731277ff569562bf7980cf/2021/10/03/0c03ca82d35deb67125cd18dbcefcb82.png)

Comment: What matters is how react's fiber traverse the nodes, not the resulting dom. If you want a more in-depth explanation on why this happens, you may want to look for a "how react fiber work" articles (there are few quite complete)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that i should dive into how react render components. Thank you for your help!!!!